# Can We post data into Google Plus using Google Plus API in iPhone. If Yes then how can we do it?

Tags: google-plus

I get stucked while sending data to Google Plus. I dont know how we do it in iphone. Any help will be appreciable. Can We post data into Google Plus using Google Plus API in iPhone. If Yes then how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Google Plus API is read-only as stated on the API website, therefore you won't be able to post anything there, at least not for now